# Hibernate Exception : unexpected token: HAVING

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, rest

I have to sort out result from DB by comparing the given distance input ie ,latitude and longitude.after surfing i have found the solution in SQL and i converted it into corresponding HQL.

***My query is:***

```
SELECT restaurantId,restaurantName,address1,((ACOS(SIN(9.9986 * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) + COS(9.9986 * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * COS((76.3125-longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distanceInKm FROM Restaurants HAVING distanceInKm<=1 ORDER BY distanceInKm ASC
```

This arises the error `Hibernate Exception : unexpected token: HAVING`.
note that in this `distanceInKm` is a virtual column.I need to add the virtual column also to the response.i tried to use `where` instead of `having` but it showing `Unknown column distanceInKm`

***Method***

```
public List<Restaurants> getRestaurantsByDistance(FilterMovieRequest filterMovieRequest) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        String sql = "SELECT restaurantId,restaurantName,address1,((ACOS(SIN(9.9986 * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) + COS(9.9986 * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * COS((76.3125-longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distanceInKm FROM Restaurants HAVING distanceInKm<=1 ORDER BY distanceInKm ASC";
        Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
        List<Restaurants> rows = query.list();
        return rows;
    }
```

***Entity***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurants")
public class Restaurants implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "restaurant_id")
    private int restaurantId;

    @Column(name = "restaurant_name")
    private String restaurantName;

    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private Integer categoryId;

    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageUrl;

    private Float longitude;

    private Float latitude;

    @Column(name = "contact_name")
    private String contactName;

    @Column(name = "primary_phone")
    private String primaryPhone;

    @Column(name = "secondary_phone")
    private String secondaryPhone;

    private String fax;

    private String address1;

    private String address2;

//Getters and setters
}
```

I have found the tags related to this but it wasn't good enough to solve my problem.

***Error :***

```
05-Aug-2015 12:16:56.017 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-103] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [WeekenterServlet] in context with path [/Weekenter] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: HAVING near line 1, column 290 [SELECT restaurantId,restaurantName,address1,((ACOS(SIN(9.9986 * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) + COS(9.9986 * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * COS((76.3125-longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distanceInKm FROM com.weekenter.www.entity.Restaurants HAVING distanceInKm<=1 ORDER BY distanceInKm ASC]] with root cause
 org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: HAVING near line 1, column 290 [SELECT restaurantId,restaurantName,address1,((ACOS(SIN(9.9986 * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) + COS(9.9986 * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * COS((76.3125-longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distanceInKm FROM com.weekenter.www.entity.Restaurants HAVING distanceInKm<=1 ORDER BY distanceInKm ASC]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1760)
    at com.weekenter.www.dao.impl.UtilityDaoImpl.getRestaurantsByDistance(UtilityDaoImpl.java:196)
    at com.weekenter.www.service.impl.UtilityServiceImpl.getRestaurantsByDistance(UtilityServiceImpl.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy938.getRestaurantsByDistance(Unknown Source)
    at com.weekenter.www.controller.UtilityController.getRestaurantsByDistance(UtilityController.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using, and is there a specific reason you're targeting Hibernate instead of JPA generally?

Comment: `Hibernate 3.5` @chrylis.. am ready to use `JPA` too if it will give me the result..

Comment: post your full stacktrace

Comment: JPA is essentially the standardized version of Hibernate, and it's preferable to use that unless you have specific reasons (usually legacy). Hibernate will still be doing the work, but you'd use a standard configuration and JPQL (which is almost HQL). The current version of Hibernate is 4.3, and I'd first suggest using a modern version before anything else.

Comment: Maybe the error is that it is using the full qualified name of `Restaurants`: `com.weekenter.www.entity.Restaurants`

Comment: Oki i will try...but now i have to follow this please tell me a solution for this now @chrylis :(

Answer (score 2):

In hibernate you can only use `HAVING` clause along with `GROUP BY` only.if you have to use `HAVING` i prefer to use `createSQLQuery` as follows.

```
public List<Restaurants> getRestaurantsByDistance(FilterMovieRequest filterMovieRequest) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Float latitude = Float.parseFloat(filterMovieRequest.Latitude() );//Get your latitude from request
            Float longitude = Float.parseFloat(filterMovieRequest.Longitude());//Get your longitude from request
            String sql = "SELECT restaurant_id,restaurant_name,category_id,image_url,longitude,latitude,contact_name,primary_phone,secondary_phone,fax,address1,address2,((ACOS(SIN(:lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) + COS(:lat * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * COS((:lon-longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distanceInKm` FROM `restaurants` HAVING `distanceInKm`<=1 ORDER BY `distanceInKm` ASC";
            Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity(Restaurants.class);
            query.setParameter("lat", latitude);
            query.setParameter("lon", longitude);
            List<Restaurants> restaurantses = query.list();
            return restaurantses;
        }
```

> Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurants")
public class Restaurants implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "restaurant_id")
    private int restaurantId;

    @Column(name = "restaurant_name")
    private String restaurantName;

    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private Integer categoryId;

    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageUrl;

    private Float longitude;

    private Float latitude;

    @Column(name = "contact_name")
    private String contactName;

    @Column(name = "primary_phone")
    private String primaryPhone;

    @Column(name = "secondary_phone")
    private String secondaryPhone;

    private String fax;

    private String address1;

    private String address2;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String distanceInKm; /*Virtual column for user responds*/

}
```

***Note : If you like to pass your virtual column ie , `distanceInKm` to user you should use only `Getter method` for that particular.and the condition `@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)` should be set***

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to encapsulate ALL your request fields in a map with parenthesis ? 

like this :

SELECT new map( restaurantId as restaurId,

restaurantName as restaurName,

address1 as adr1,

((ACOS(SIN(9.9986 * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) + COS(9.9986 * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * COS((76.3125-longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distanceInKm)

FROM .....